# Nswag/Angular display API error message in error event

Tags: angular, nswag, nswagstudio

First of All I was using the CQRS architecture for the back-end API and using NSWAG as an API connection; that generates API Endpoints in service proxy for the front-end Angular.

I did simple validation for my POST API, while testing the created API the result was different in DevTools.

In Network tab the validation that i expected was occured however in Console tab
the result is different; As a matter of fact that result is i need.

Here's my problem. In detail with image

code for API call

```
     saveLocationType(createLocationTypeCommand){
    this.tenantService.createLocationType(createLocationTypeCommand).subscribe(result => {
   // Do Something
    }, error => {
      console.log(error); 
    })
  }
```

This is the validation result coming from my API in Network Tab that was correct.
[image]

This is my problem in Console the result here must be the same in Network Tab.
[image]

I believe the result in console was coming from service proxy since that's the one generates/formatting the APIs for the front-end.

Is there a way to configure the generated service proxy of NSWAG? or is there other way to show the error message in Console tab same in Network Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using these reference:

- https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2327
- https://lurumad.github.io/problem-details-an-standard-way-for-specifying-errors-in-http-api-responses-asp.net-core

Snippet in C# Web API that i implemented to fixed my problem

```
  [HttpPost("setup/locationType", Name = "createLocationType")]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ValidationProblemDetails), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLocationTypeAsync([FromBody] CreateLocationTypeCommand command)
        {
            try
            {
                var commandResult = await _mediator.Send(command);

                if (!commandResult)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails
                {
                    Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    Type = "",
                    Title = "Create Location Type",
                    Detail = ex.Message,
                    Instance = HttpContext.Request.Path
                };

                return new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
                {
                    ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" },
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                };
            }

        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the angular http client, try to use the responseType text option.

```
return this.http.post(url,body, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe()
```

The client tries to handle the response as responseType: 'json' as default.
He tries to parse this response as a json and fails and raises this error.

More infos about non Json responsebodies you can find here: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data